# unable to insert data in a stl map of map of map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

I have following map declaration :

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>> m;
```

I tried inserting data in following way :

```
m.insert({ "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS", { "REG_SZ", { "SystemSKU", "SystemSKU" } } });
```

but its not working , what is correct syntax to insert data?

Comment: This might be the best title i've ever seen

Comment: Waht are you trying to do?

Comment: @Treycos : i just kept it straight .

Comment: Problem with your `insert` operation is that you are creating the entry but not the inner map. By putting extra one opening and closing braces for each inner map, you can achieve the same goal. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot get it to work with initializer lists you could use the classical way:

```
m["HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS"]["REG_SZ"]["SystemSKU"] = "SystemSKU";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ideone.com/ngarYI) list initialization will work for you:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>> m{{"HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS", 
                        {{ "REG_SZ", {{ "SystemSKU", "SystemSKU" }} }}
            }};
```

Or, use insert

```
m.insert({"HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS", 
           {{ "REG_SZ", {{ "SystemSKU", "SystemSKU" }} }} //create inner maps using double braces 
        });
```

It uses std::map's list constructor (the one that takes a std::initializer_list>).

It is little tricky to read and write though.

Note that the double braces **{{ or }}** are used together. *Inner ones* **{}** marks the **single entry** in a map, and *outer one* **{}** represents the **map as a whole**.

Liked other answer for simplicity.

Comment: this declaration have some problem , check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895375/map-set-iterators-incompatible-c-program-crashed-during-initialization

Comment: There is no error in the code presented in the link provided by you as I tried running it.

Comment: it will give error in ms visual studio 2013 , but not in ms visual studio 2015 and g++ , I am using ms visual studio 2013.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to initialize the map like this, but this does not work for "inserting" into an already constructed map, or is there a similar way to insert?

Comment: @Rumpel. It works very well for insertion as well. For inserting you need to put entry as parameter. See for example how it works: http://ideone.com/pbcJ1v